# Replace multiple lines in a text file by a fixed pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

Okay, looking for a quick way to do this. I have a list of line numbers that need to be changed in a text data file. The 16 bit pattern on that line can be anything but I need to change to change it to read `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` based solely on the line number. Again I have a long list of line numbers I know that need to be changed. There is no discernible pattern to the lines that need to be changed. (I did not write the data pattern but I know what lines need to be changed to read all X's.) I read through a lot of the answers here and none really quite deal with this.

If this isn't clear I'll put it another way...

Change lines 26115, 32198, 37256, 40001, 40023 in a file to read `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`. I have over 100,000 lines that need changing in a 1.9 million line file.

Answer (score 3):

As an extension of @Gilles's answer, since you say you have the line numbers that need changed in a file (which I will assume is sorted and called `linums`)

```
awk '
  BEGIN { getline NEXT < "linums" }
  NR == NEXT { $0 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; getline NEXT < "linums" }
  1
'
```

This scales well to changing several thousand lines without having to manually type these several thousand line numbers.

Alternatively, with a slight modification, you can take either the line numbers or the file to be changed on `stdin`.  I'd make a script for this (I've called it `redact.awk`)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    LINUMS = ARGV[1]
    ARGV[1] = ARGV[2]
    --ARGC
    getline NEXT < LINUMS
}
NR == NEXT {
    $0 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    getline NEXT < LINUMS
}
1
```

Then you can use any of:

```
$ ./redact.awk linums file-to-be-changed
$ ./redact.awk - file-to-be-changed
$ ./redact.awk linums -
$ ./redact.awk linums
```

(The last two are equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

Either sed or awk works well for this task.

```
sed '
    26115 s/.*/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
    32198 s/.*/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
    37256 s/.*/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
    40001 s/.*/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
    40023 s/.*/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
'
```

```
awk '
  NR==26115 || NR==32198 || NR==37256 || NR==40001 || NR==40023 {$0 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
  1
'
```

(The lone `1` prints all lines, after the possible transformation performed by the preceding code.)

Comment: I think I'll go with the sed solution as I already have the line numbers in a file. Thanks for the quick response. The awk solution would be a bit too much typing. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '1{x;s/^/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/;x;}
   26115bp
   32198bp
   37256bp
   40001bp
   40023bp
   d
   :p
   g
' data_file
```

We first stuff the hold space with the desired pattern `XXXXXXXXX`  and then recall that only for the desired line numbers by jumping to the label :p which shall retrieve hold space which will then implicitly get carried over to stdout. The non-matching lines are deleted (change the `d` to `b` if you want to keep them).

Answer (score 1):

Since the replacement is static and since the operation of replacing multiple lines is so simple in `sed`, one could possibly create one big `sed` script to do the work.

Assuming that you have the line numbers in a separate file, `linenos.txt`, one line number per line, then we can produce the (GNU) `sed` script through

```
$ awk '{ printf("%dc XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n", $0) }' linenos.txt >script.sed
```

or

```
$ awk '{ print $0, "c XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" }' linenos.txt >script.sed
```

Then, it's a matter of applying it to a file:

```
$ sed -f script.sed file >file.new
```

Note: I have never run an exceedingly large `sed` script, so I don't know how GNU `sed` handles it performance-wise.